How to write JUnit test for Gateway Application in Spring Boot Microservices
I have a problem to implement some JUnit test for Gateway Application in Spring Boot Microservices
Here is the Gateway Service Application shown below
@EnableDiscoveryClient
@SpringBootApplication
public class GatewayServiceApplication {

    /**
     * The main method that starts the Spring Boot application.
     *
     * @param args The command-line arguments passed to the application.
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(GatewayServiceApplication.class, args);
    }

}

Next, I try to write its JUnit tests shown below
@SpringBootTest
class GatewayServiceApplicationTest {

    @Autowired
    private ApplicationContext context;

    @DisplayName("Application context loads without errors")
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {
        assertThat(context).isNotNull();
    }

    @DisplayName("Gateway Service starts successfully via main method")
    @Test
    void mainMethodTest() {
        GatewayServiceApplication.main(new String[]{});
    }

    @Test
    @DisplayName("Gateway Service is enabled and running")
    void gatewayServiceIsEnabledAndRunning() {
        assertThat(context.getBean(GatewayServiceApplication.class)).isNotNull();
    }

}

When I run any test, I got this error message shown below


java.lang.StackOverflowError
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.hash(IdentityHashMap.java:295)
    at java.util.IdentityHashMap.put(IdentityHashMap.java:426)
    at java.util.Collections$SetFromMap.add(Collections.java:5461)

How can I fix it?
As you know, this service is up after eureka server is up
I have a problem to implement some JUnit test for Gateway Application in Spring Boot Microservices.
The aim is to run all JUnit tests in GatewayServiceApplicationTest

The main() method of the Spring Boot Application is not covered by
the unit/integration tests as the Spring Boot tests don't invoke the main()
method to start the Spring Boot application.
Since you are passing specific another argument in the main method, it may
require Junit for the same.
you can refer below links for the same.
How to JUnit Test Spring-Boot's Application.java
application-java

As you know, start web dependency cannot use Gateway Service. How can I fix stackoverflow issue?
